# Static array declaration

Tags: c++

Having simple *c++* program like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

template <typename T>
char BinVal(T SrcVal) {
    
    //short BitsCount = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    short BitsCount = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    short SeparatorCount = sizeof(T)*2-1;
    short SeparatorSize = CHAR_BIT/2+1;
    static char BinValStr[ BitsCount + SeparatorCount ] = {0};
  
    printf("BitsCount: %d\n", BitsCount);
    printf("SeparatorCount: %d\n", SeparatorCount);
    printf("BinValStr size: %d\n", BitsCount + SeparatorCount);
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    for ( i=BitsCount+SeparatorCount-1; i>=0; i-- ) {

        if( (j+1)%SeparatorSize == 0) {
            BinValStr[i] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            if( SrcVal&1 == 1 )
                BinValStr[i] = '1';
            else
                BinValStr[i] = '0';
                SrcVal >>=1;
        }
        j++;
    
    }
    
    char y='o';
    return y;
    //return BinValStr;
    //printf("\nStr: %s", BinValStr);
}

int main(){
    
    short val = 0b0000'0100'0001'0110; //18 dec
    printf("\nStr: %c", BinVal(val) );
}
```

i get "*storage size of ‘BinValStr’ isn’t constant*" error.

When i make the *BinValStr* var "normal", local everything is OK. Why does making the variable static gives me the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What you have shown is not a simple c++ program. It does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, it can not be reproduced: https://godbolt.org/z/EocjEh

Comment: @Const you're running it in O3 mode without static checks.. template wasn't checked\instantiated

Comment: Ok here is the complete program

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to your question, "Swift - Friday Pie" has already covered that. Instead I want to point out a small issue in some of your other code:

`if( SrcVal&1 == 1 )`

While this works, it may not work like you think. In short: `==` binds harder (has higher precedence) than `&`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

This means that the above `if` goes like this:

`1 == 1` => `true`. `SrcVal & true` => `SrcVal & 1` => does the bitwise AND and returns 1 or 0. That number is then interpreted as a truth value and gives the result you want. So why is it a problem when it works? Well, lets say that you want the same test again, but now you are looking for when the first bit of `ScrVal` is 0, so you write:

`if( SrcVal&1 == 0 )`

And now it just never works because: `1 == 0` => `false`. `ScrVal & false` => `ScrVal & 0` => `0`.

How to fix it? The two easy options:

- Wrap the bitwise AND in parenthesis: `if( (SrcVal & 1) == 1 )`
- Omit the comparison: `if( SrcVal & 1 )`

Comment: I guess OP needs `std::bitset` instead of any array type.

Answer (score 2):

You attempted to use *varaibles* as size of array,  while you need  compile-time values. ISO C++ doesn't allow to allocate array dynamically (GNU extension for variable length arrays is an exception), thus expression for size of array should be `constexpr`

```
template <typename T>
char BinVal(T SrcVal) { 
    constexpr short BitsCount = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    constexpr short SeparatorCount = sizeof(T)*2-1;
    
    constexpr short SeparatorSize = CHAR_BIT/2+1;
    static char BinValStr[ BitsCount + SeparatorCount ] = {0};
```

Pre-C++11 variant could be just `static const` or using  `integral_constant` or similar construct.

Comment: Also, [`<array>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @DevSolar if allowed (and supported), yes, of course.  It also a good learning experience to peek into implementation of those simple templates, `std::array`, `integral_constant` essentially do something like this inside.

Comment: While `std::array` probably is a better idea than []-array, not that it also requires its size to be a compile-time constant. So this answer applies there too.

Comment: Thx. guys for help, i suspected that the key is just making the variables `const`, but what's REALLY bizarre - when i remove `static` keyword form _BinValStr_ definition (making it `local`) the code DO WORKS (no errors or warnings) even there is no`const` medifier for the variables!???

Comment: @DarosRT10 you likely use GNU compiler then, or compatible. That's VLA, a C feature which isn't supported by C++ standard. Essentislly it's a dynamic array in stack with limitation that you cannot pass it out of function. VLA cannot be static or global. E.g. g++ supports it by default